# making a generator thread-safe

Tags: python, multithreading, generator

I am trying to write a thread-safe generator.  The generator code is shown below:

```
def jobs(users):
    result = [1 for _ in users]
    while(sum(result)>0):
        for n,usr in enumerate(users):
            if usr.hasQuery():
                yield usr
            else:
                result[n] = 0
```

I tried the following approach ([source](http://anandology.com/blog/using-iterators-and-generators/)):

```
class ThreadsafeIter(object):
    def __init__(self, it):
        self.lock = threading.Lock()
        self.it = it.__iter__()

    def __iter__(self): return self

    def __next__(self):
        with self.lock:
            return next(self.it)

def threadsafe_gen(f):
    def g(*a, **kw):
        return ThreadsafeIter(f(*a, **kw))
    return g
```

Then decorated jobs() using @threadsafe_gen.  This thread-safe generator is used as follows:

```
genjobs = jobs(users)
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
pool = ThreadPool(processes=2)
pool.map(worker, genjobs)
```

where worker is defined as

```
def worker(usr):
    usr.runNextQuery()
```

The instance usr has a pyODBC connection to a database and a list of queries.  When runNextQuery is called, it should run the next query.  Using the above code, all the connections remain idle and no query is run.  Any idea why?

Comment: Thanks @martineau.  That was a typo which is now fixed in the code above.  The problem remains.

Comment: The above code works as expected when I do not use parallelism `list(map(worker, genjobs))`.  @dano  any ideas?

Comment: This code works fine for me (though I used dummy objects in the `users` list). Try adding some print statements to trace what's actually happening. Also worth noting: When you use `pool.map`, it internally calls `list(genjobs)` prior to sending any work to the worker processes. If you don't want this behavior, you need to use `pool.imap` instead.

Comment: Also, using @username only actually sends an alert if `username` has edited/commented on the question already. It just so happened that I looked at this question and saw my name, though :)

Comment: I don't really see the point of making `jobs` thread safe. Whether you use `pool.map` or `pool.imap` the `jobs` generator will only be run in the same thread that calls either of these functions. The `multiprocessing` package handles a lot of these synchronization issues for you. Note also that `ThreadPool` is undocumented, you should use its documented name `multiprocessing.dummy.Pool` instead.

Comment: what's the  expected output?